# android click image to zoom in (larger than screen) and move around, and click again to go back to default size

Tags: android, image, click, zooming

I've done my searches extensively for sure, but I haven't come across exactly what I'm looking for.  As such, I haven't any code to show for what I want to do.  I want to know if it's possible, first of all, and then get a lead on how to implement such an action.

To keep my app simple, I'd really like to avoid starting a new activity, which seems to be involved in many of the "solutions" that I've seen.

My setup isn't anything special, just a layout with some textviews, buttons, and an image that's about as large as the screen.

I want the user to be able to click the image, and the image will "zoom" or "enlarge" to about 4-5x the size, obviously much of the image will then be off screen.  Then, the user should be able to drag the image around to view the entire image as they wish.  When they're done looking at the image, they should be able to click to go back to the original size.

I'm sure this will warrant a separate image for each size (one for the original, and a larger more detailed image for the enlarged version).  Though, the simpler the better.  If I can maintain one larger detailed image and scale it down for the standard view before it's clicked, that'd be great.

I'm assuming they'll be a click listener on the image, but I'm not sure how to do what I want without starting a new activity entirely, then upon clicking again, going back to the original activity.  Can it be done in the same activity?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I just had an idea.  I could have the larger image in a relative view and make it invisible/gone, then make it visible upon click of the original/main image. Clicking the large image will make itself invisible/gone again.  But, assuming this works, I do'nt konw how to set the action of dragging it around and boundaries to make sure you can't drag it outside of the screen entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hopes that this helps someone else and that my solution will suffice in fixing someone else's issue, I'm going to answer my own question with what I found to be a good fix.

To keep it as simple as possible (as it seems that implementing such a feature requires more extensive work that I feel should be necessary), I used the method of toggling hidden/invisible views.

```
<FrameLayout>


    <!--Main Activity-->
    <LinearLayout>

        <!--Primary Image-->
        <ImageView
             android:onClick="makeZoomVisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>



    <!--ScrollView Holder for Enlarged Image-->
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:visibility="gone">

        <!--Enlarged Image-->
        <ImageView
            android:onClick="makeZoomInvisible"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

The base layout is a Frame layout, which allows me to place the Enlarged Image holder (horizontal scroll view) on top of everything else since it comes after the main activity view (linear layout).

Once the primary image is clicked, it calls the method "makeZoomVisible", which as you may guess, toggles the visibility for the horizontal scroll view which holds the enlarged image.  The image is scaled up to as large as the height of the screen allows.  This works for me because my app is portrait only, and allows the image to scale up approximately 4x the size (a 2x2 of the original image size, just for comparison).  Since the image maxes out at the height of the screen, there's no need to scroll/drag up and down.  But the horizontal scroll allows the image to be moved side to side to view the whole image.

Clicking the enlarged image calls the method "makeZoomInvisible" which toggles its own visibility, clearing it away and allowing the user to see the main layout of the activity again.

This is the best option for me as a new Android app developer because of its simplicity.  To refrain from switching activities, saving/pausing the current activity, implementing 3rd party libraries to include a horizonal+vertical scroll, or pinch zoom and drag features I'm able to achieve what I need for my app.

Hopefully this helps someone else out that may be looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

i have use [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library in my project for Zooming images and its very simple to use its helps you ...

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

**JAVA:**
    PhotoView mImageView;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
mImageView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

// Set the Drawable displayed
Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

    // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming    functionality.
mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
}


// If you later call mImageView.setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap/setImageResource/etc then you just need to call
  attacher.update();
```

**XML:**

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
   android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:padding="20dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I may attempt this later if all else fails.  But at this point, I'm not sure how to implement another library like this.  And I'd rather use a method directly from Android until I become comfortable enough to use something from a third party.

Comment: its very simple and easy to use just import this lib as you import other project and right click on project > properties> android >add lib and use like normal in project :)

Comment: Is there any reason to think that I (or the users) would run into issues with compatibility over different versions if I were to use this library?

Comment: this lib support  API 2.2 and up its like you use PhotoView instead ImageView

Answer (score 1):

I know you decided to implement simple transition yourself without using 3rd party libs. But if someone else is looking for more complex solution, I can suggest to try [this library](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews), it allows zooming from i.e. RecyclerView items to ViewPager with animation and includes zoom/pan/rotation features as well.

(Note, I'm the developer of this library)

Simple usage example:

1. Add regular `ImageView` and `GestureImageView` into layout:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/image_small"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <com.alexvasilkov.gestures.views.GestureImageView
           android:id="@+id/image_full"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. Set same image into both views:

   ```
   smallImage.setImageDrawable(...);
   fullImage.setImageDrawable(...);
   ```
3. Start animation:

   ```
   fullImage.getPositionAnimator().enter(smallImage, true);
   ```

For more info see [documentation](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews/wiki) and [sample project](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews/tree/master/sample).

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do this would be to use a custom ImageView to handle the zooming and dragging of the image that way you can keep it in the same layout without having to start a new activity.

You should check out the [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) library. It contains a [custom ImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java) that allows pinch zoom, double tap to zoom, dragging, and the ability to manually set the zoom of the image.

If don't want to include the full library a simple way to add this functionality would be to copy the [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java) java class into a package in your app (eg com.myapp.views).

Then in your xml layout instead of using:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
```

Change your image to use the path of the custom view class:

```
<com.myapp.views.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
```

Comment: This sounds like something I may be able to attempt, though right now it's out of my league.  I'm always up to learn new things, but I'm not sure at this point how to do what you're saying.

Comment: I would definitely recommend starting to get familiar with using third-party libraries. They will save you hours and hours of time, no need to reinvent the wheel when someone has already created one for you. 

I've updated my answer to get you started, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yeah I hear ya, and I don't disagree.  I just really like to know/understand what I'm doing.  So yeah, I'm sure I'll go this route if I don't get another solution that better fits.